# How do I format an NSInteger to represent minutes as zero padded digits like 00, 05...?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview, uidatepicker, nsnumber, nsinteger

I'm building a UIPickerView to resemble a custom subclass of UIDatePicker, timepicker style.

Anyway, the minutes component should have numbers for every 5 minutes, starting with 00, 05, and then 10, 15, etc...

How do I get the zero number padding formatting on the left for the 00 and 05 minutes mark?

I suspect I have to delve into the [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html) class, but I have no experience whatsoever with it, apart from it looking like quite a scary class, and I was hoping someone could give me a basic implementation in a quick punch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Convert your `int` to NSStrings like so:

```
[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02d", 1];
```

This int will be converted to 01.

Comment: Not quite what I had in mind, but since I have to return strings for the picker's rows anyway, this will work just fine. Thanks for the heads up.

Comment: To be avoid warnings today (2019+) NSInteger formatter must be like: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%02ld", (long)value]; Thank you for answer.